# Reaching keys and values from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

I have a list containing many dictionaries, I need to reach keys and values for each dict:

```
[{'keys1.1' = 'value1.1','key1.2'='values1.2'},{'keys2.1'='value2.1'},{'key3.1'='value3.1'}]
```

How can I get those keys and values?

Comment: What are you trying to *do* with the dictionaries? Reaching them is trivial, just use indexing or looping.

Comment: Disagree with the close: if this wasn't a real question, Python 3.3's [collections.ChainMap](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop over the `dict`s in a `for-loop`:

```
list_of_dicts = [{'keys1.1' : 'value1.1',
                   'key1.2':'values1.2'},
                 {'keys2.1':'value2.1'},
                 {'key3.1':'value3.1'}]


for item in list_of_dicts:
  for key, value in item.iteritems()
    print key, value
    print "The key is {0} with a value of {1}".format(key, value)
#or
for item in list_of_dicts:
  for key in item.keys():
    print item[key]
    print "The key is {0} with a value of {1}".format(key, item[key])
```

Comment: you do know about `for key, value in item.iteritems()` right?

Comment: Good call. Editing that it now.